# Convert values into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this column:

```
floor
---------
dep:first
dep:second
dep:third
dep:fourth
```

And I want to make it like this :

```
DEP
------
first
second
third
fourth
```

I am trying this :

```
select
    max(case when floor = 'dep:first' then 'first' end) DEP,
    max(case when floor = 'dep:second' then 'second' end) DEP,
    max(case when floor = 'dep:third' then 'third' end) DEP,
    max(case when floor = 'dep:fourth' then 'fourth' end) DEP,
from 
    db.table
```

But the result returns the DEP column 4 times:

```
DEP    |DEP    |DEP     |DEP    |
-------|-------|--------|-------|
first  |second |third   |fourth |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using `replace()` or `stuff()`?

```
select replace(floor, 'dep:', '')
```

or:

```
select stuff(floor, 1, 4, '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I thought too the first option but I wanted to see the one that I asked. Can you please explain me the second option you have provided?

Comment: The documentation explains how the function works, @Thkas . [STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)